# MongoDB/GraphQL: Model.find() to get posts that userId is in likes

Tags: javascript, mongodb, graphql

in my resolvers I have a method to find user likes with

```
async function userBookmarks(args, context) {
const user = checkAuth(context);
const posts = await Post.find({likes: {userId: user.id}})
return posts; }
```

But GraphQL returns an empty array.

For reference, the Post model is

```
likes: [
{
  userId: String,
  createdAt: String
}],
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar problem and fixed it by defining the MongoDB Collection name in the bottom of my MongoDB Schema.

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    location: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    }
}, { collection : 'Users' });
```

**EDIT:**
Use $elemMatch to query several fields.

```
const posts = await User.find({likes: {$elemMatch: {userId: user.id}}})
```

Comment: Hi, I don't think the collection name is the problem since my other queries involving it worked such as liking a post.

Comment: Hi again, sorry for the delay, but I recreated your set-up got it working on my end and edited my answer. Hope it may be of use.